# Datasource is required though it has been specified and worked earlier

Tags: spring-batch

I have been working on a spring boot application where the application works fine. When i tried to introduce the following code

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
public class EmployeeDbCreateWriter extends JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> {

    @Autowired
    DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Employee> employeeList) throws Exception {

    .....
    .... 
   }
  }
```

i end up with the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A DataSource or a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is 
required.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
at 
org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet
(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
... 57 more
```

Configure and component scan is given is working fine before introducing the above class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = 
{"com.emp.repositories","com.emp2.repositories"})
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.emp","com.emp2"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.emp.models","com.emp2.models"})
@EnableCaching
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Slf4j
public class EmpConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to set it on the super class as well. But why are you extending the `JdbcBatchItemWriter`? That isn't really meant to be extended but rather configured.

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to define the writer in a separate class instead of configuring since i have classifier class - DatabaseOperationClassifier implements Classifier and the writer is dynamic based on the input choosen. Please advise

Comment: Still I don't see the reason for extending it, nonetheless the issue is that the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` needs a datasource, you ommit it. Regarding the extension you extend `JdbcBatchItemWriter` but basically ignore everything that is being offered by that class by re-implementing the `write` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum Reason: I want to process a CSV file and load the contents or rows of it to DB or publish as topic to AMQ or publish as topic to Kafka based on the property attribute defined in the application.properties file. Please advise as these 3 are 3 different writers. It should work based on the configuration. So i used OperationClassifier implements Classifier where we can define multiple writer and return the writer based on the property value. Please advise on how to do this.

Comment: You still don't need the subclassses, again just configuration of those writers. You don't need the classifier at all, just configure the proper writer based on that property (using a factory, or conditional beans). None of which (nor dos the classifier) need the subclass.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please help me with a code snippet to understand? That would really helps me.

Comment: No as that wasn't the question, also that would be undoable as we don't know what is so special about this writer that you decided to subclass it (in other words we don't know what is being written).

Answer (score 0):

Per what I see in the [JdbcBatchItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html) it requires Datasource or JdbcTemplate to be provided and it is not aware of the autowired datasource in the child class.

You could try something like this and provide datasource manually in the `PostConstruct` method

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
public  class EmployeeDbCreateWriter extends JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> {
    
    @Autowired 
    DataSource dataSource;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    ....
}
```

However per @M.Deinum comments is it doubtful that there is a good reasons to extend `JdbcBatchItemWriter`  and that this class was meant to be extended.

Comment: I want to process a CSV file and load the contents or rows of it to DB or publish as topic to AMQ or publish as topic to Kafka based on the property attribute defined in the application.properties file. Please advise as these 3 are 3 different writers. It should work based on the configuration. So i used OperationClassifier implements Classifier where we can define multiple writer and return the writer based on the property value. Please advise on how to do this.